# Checkmark in Django, getting which one is checked

Tags: django, forms

I'm new in django and trying to set a form like this:
[my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uSz7.png)

So far I did this:

result.html:

```
....
<form id="form" name="form" method="GET">
<p>
          <label class="container">Yes
          <input type="checkbox" name="1">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
            <br>
          <label class="container">No
          <input type="checkbox" name="0">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
            <br>
          <label class="container">No proper image
          <input type="checkbox" name="2">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
            <br>
 </p>
 ....
```

in views.py:

```
def result(request):
    ....
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {}
        context['form'] = FormYesOrNo()

    ....
    return render(request, template_name, response1)
```

in forms.py:

```
choices = [(1, 'Yes'), (0, 'No'), (2, 'none')]

class FormYesOrNo(forms.Form):
    def PrdJudgeRe(self):
        PrdJudge = forms.TypedChoiceField(
            choices=choices,
            coerce=str)
    return (PrdJudge)
```

Now in views.py I do not know how to get the checked box index or value. when running server and for example I check yes in the log I see this:
"GET /result/?1=on HTTP/1.1" 200 1389
which means that it can see 1 is on but how can I get that?

I also used this code but this form_is_valid() is not valid apparently, and I don't know why:

in views.py:

```
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {}
        formdj = FormYesOrNo(request.GET or None)
        context['formdj'] = formdj
        if request.GET:
            print ("sHos")
            if formdj.is_valid():
                temp = formdj.cleaned_data.get("PrdJudge")
                print("fill", type(temp))
                # print(type(temp))
    else:
        print("SHILL" )
```

it returns "sHos"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since no one answered, I found the solution and let it be for others:

in views.py:

```
....
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if '0' in request.GET:
            print('No', 0)
        if '1' in request.GET:
            print('yes', 0)
        if '2' in request.GET:
            print('Not a proper image', 0)
....
```

very simple method!. Thanks